# How to Populate known_hosts if you already have the .pub files

Tags: ssh

I am trying to automatically populate the known_hosts file. I have the .pub key for each of the computers I'm trying to populate. Is there anyway I can avoid MITM, given that I have both the private and public key?

Comment: You **only** need public files for this!!! If you hold ***both the private and public key*** from different hosts in same place, this could become a security flaw! Care to not let somone stole your store!!

Answer (score 0):

## 1. first prepare your `know_host` file with something like:

```
while read keytyp pubkey rootAt; do
    read fqdn foo foo ip < <(host ${rootAt#*@})
    if [ "$foo" = "address" ]; then
        echo ${rootAt#*@},$fqdn,$ip $keytyp $pubkey
    else
        echo "Error: can't resolv ${rootAt#*@}" >&2
    fi
done < <(cat pathWithDotPubFiles/allHosts/ssh*.pub) >known_hosts
```

Unhashed file could look like:

```
targethost,targethost.example.com,123.45.67.89 ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...nBvu
targethost,targethost.example.com,123.45.67.89 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2V...KU0=
targethost,targethost.example.com,123.45.67.89 ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3N...qdeW
```

## 2. Hash your new `known_hosts` file:

```
ssh-keygen -H -f known_hosts
Original contents retained as known_hosts.old
WARNING: known_hosts.old contains unhashed entries
Delete this file to ensure privacy of hostnames
```

## 3. Move your new file to right place:

```
mv known_hosts ~/.ssh
shred known_hosts.old
rm known_hosts.old
```

Comment: I tried this but it was throwing errors because some of my files end with something like name@ComputerName. I tried creating a known_hosts file with:

targethost,192.168.x.x ssh-rsa AAA..Gd (I copied the content from the .pub file that correlates to the key used for authentication) but that did not work even after hashing the file

Could you please elaborate on how to manually do this without the code?

Comment: sshd puiblic key files could look like `ssh-cipher, space, public-key, space, root@hostname`. My script sample will work if `hostname` do resolv!

Comment: `know_host` file must NOT have spaces between hostname and ip! Only coma!! `targethost,targethost.example.com,123.45.67.89` *space* `ssh-cipher` *space* `Public_Key` **.**